# nginx's proxy_pass redirects me to another URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, proxypass, qutebrowser

I'm building a website with nginx:

```
server_name example.xyz;
location /9rJQi6opvrkXBhp2S7nqQ2/ { 
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/; 
}
```

This is my Flask app (but I don't think Flask is the problem):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'root from flask'

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return '/test from flask'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

From all browsers, if I go to https://example.xyz/9rJQi6opvrkXBhp2S7nqQ2/test I got the response *"/test from flask"*.

If I go to https://example.xyz/9rJQi6opvrkXBhp2S7nqQ2/ with Firefox I get *"root from flask"*, **but** with Qutebrowser I get redirected to https://example.xyz/.

With a simpler string (instead of *"9rJQi6opvrkXBhp2S7nqQ2"*) I have no problems; but I'm not sure it always behave the same.
Which is the problem, nginx or qutebrowser?

Answer (score 0):

I simply deleted the ~/.cache/qutebrowser directory, and now it works.